# Create list of sheets via VBA and insert it into a certain area of a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a list of all sheets in my Excel file.
The list should be inserted into `Sheet3.Range("B5:B50")` 
(I do not have more than 50 sheets in my spreadsheet).

Therefore, I tried to go with this VBA:

```
Sub ListSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
For Each ws In Worksheets
Sheet3.Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
x = x + 1
Next ws
End Sub
```

This VBA creates the list of the sheets but it does not insert it into my desired range `B5:B50`. The list is created within **Column A** starting at **A1**.

How do I have to change this code to get the list into `Sheet3.Range("B5:B50")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opiton 1:** Range in which list of sheets is inserted is **unlimited**:

```
Sub ListSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet, x As Long, r As Range
Set r = Sheet3.Range("B5")
For Each ws In Worksheets
   x = x + 1
   r.Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
Next ws
End Sub
```

**Option 2:** Range in which list of sheets is inserted is **limited**:

```
Sub ListSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet, x As Long, r As Range
Set r = Sheet3.Range("B5:B50")
For Each ws In Worksheets
    x = x + 1
    If x > r.Count Then Exit Sub
    r.Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, thanks for the code. Works really nice. I was wondering is there also way to limit it in the range B5:B50. For example in case I have more than 100 sheets but I only want to insert the first 45 into B5:B50?

Comment: Yes I have added an If to check the value of x compared to the number of cells in `r`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional help.

Comment: My pleasure. I'm happy with your suggested edit but note that I re-instated the indentation which I think is a good habit to get into. Makes code much more readable and can help you spot errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Offset` to do this.

```
Sub ListSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Sheet3.Range("B5").Offset(x) = ws.Name
        x = x + 1
    Next ws
End Sub
```

If you want to restrict this list to a certain number of sheets (e.g. the first 45), add an additional condition.

```
Sub ListSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If x < 45 Then
            Sheet3.Range("B5").Offset(x) = ws.Name
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have an `x` - use the worksheet's `Index` to dictate the position.

```
Sub ListSheets()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B5:B50")

For Each Wksht In Worksheets
    If Wksht.Index <= rng.Cells.Count Then rng.Cells(Wksht.Index, 1) = Wksht.Name
Next

End Sub
```

This will prevent writing beyond the specified range also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case concatenation is your friend:

```
Sub ListSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
x = 5
For Each ws In Worksheets
Sheet3.Range("B" & x) = ws.Name
x = x + 1
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in an alternative method using sheet.count in For i loop

```
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Range("B" & i + 4).Value2 = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
```